# How to use the parameters from response in a request's URL parameter in karate

Tags: automation, automated-tests, karate

I need to use the parameters from one request in another request's URL parameter. The code snippet is as follows:

```
  Scenario: Lists all Students (limited information)
    Given path "/students"
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * def student = response.students[0]
    Then print student

  Scenario: GET - Retrieve the complete details of a Student 
    Given path "/students/" + student.id 
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    Then print response
```

On using this karate throws the following exception:

```
ReferenceError: "student" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

What went wrong here? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the line containing the second Scenario keyword. You need to have both the requests within a single scenario.